# Checking whether an expression is a valid formula

Tags: java, recursion

> ***Recursion Question:*** A **formula** is defined as a string
> containing positive single digits numbers, variables, and operations
> (such that: +,-,/,*,%). In  addition, the string doesn't contain space
> bars. Each operation  between two numbers or variables is separated
> with brackets - "()".
>
> Valid formulas would be:  ((6+x)*(4+2)), (((9*4)+(x+8))*(6-5)), 6,
> (3+1), etc...
>
> Invalid formulas would be: -6, (1+*(x+2)*(1-6)), ( (6+x)),   10,
> 2+x, (33+3), ((1+2)), etc...
>
> Write a boolean recursion function which gets a string - "s" and
> returns true if he is a valid formula, and false otherwise.

- The code has to be written via java.

---

***My attempt:*** I have tried the following, putting in mind that the number of "(" is less equal to the number of ")", however, it doesn't right since: "((1+2))" isn't a valid formula. So I have written the following:

```
 public static boolean isFormula(String s) {
        return calc(s, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    public static boolean calc(String s, int oc, int l, int r, int g) {
        if (s == "") {
            return (oc <= 1 && (l == r));
        }
        char c = s.charAt(0);
        char e = s.charAt(s.length() - 1);
        if (g == 0) {
            if (!(op(s))) return false;
            else {
                return calc(s, oc, l, r, g + 1);
            }
        }
        if (c == '(') {
            return calc(s.substring(1), oc, l + 1, r, g);
        } else if (c == ')') {
            return calc(s.substring(1), oc, l, r + 1, g);
        } else if ((c >= '0' && c <= '9') || c == 'x') {
            if (oc <= 1) {
                return calc(s.substring(1), 0, l, r, g);
            }
        } else if ((c == '+' || c == '-' || c == '*' || c == '/')) {
            return calc(s.substring(1), oc + 1, l, r, g);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static boolean op(String s) {
        int count = 0;
        if (s.charAt(0) == '+' || s.charAt(0) == '-' || s.charAt(0) == '*' || s.charAt(0) == '/') {
            count++;
        }
        String d = s.replace("(", "");
        if (d.charAt(0) == '+' || d.charAt(0) == '-' || d.charAt(0) == '*' || d.charAt(0) == '/') {
            count++;
        }
        d = d.replace(")", "");
        d = d.replace("+", ",");
        d = d.replace("-", ",");
        d = d.replace("*", ",");
        d = d.replace("/", ",");
        String[] words = d.split(",");
        int sum = words.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if (s.charAt(i) == '+' || s.charAt(i) == '-' || s.charAt(i) == '/' || s.charAt(i) == '*') {
                count++;
            }
        }
        if (s.contains(" ")) return false;
        return (count <= sum - 1);
    }
```

---

***Thoughts:***
I find this question very complex, and I don't know how to arrange the code, because it doesn't seem that my way is correct and and it is so messy. I will be glad for some help. I put a lot of effort into writing this post. Thank you!

Comment: You wrote that all numbers in the expression must be single digit numbers. In other words only the numbers 0 to 9 are allowed. Is that correct? What about the variables? I could not find any conditions regarding variables. From your question, it appears that the only valid variable is `x`. Is that correct?

Comment: @Abra all you said correct :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
static final Pattern DIGIT_OR_X = Pattern.compile("[\\dx]");
static final Pattern OPERATION = Pattern.compile("\\([\\dx][+*/%-][\\dx]\\)");

public static boolean isFormula(String s) {
    while (true) {
        if (DIGIT_OR_X.matcher(s).matches())
            return true;
        String rep = OPERATION.matcher(s).replaceAll("x");
        if (rep.equals(s))
            return false;
        s = rep;
    }
}
```

Test cases:

```
assertTrue(isFormula("((6+x)*(4+2))"));
assertTrue(isFormula("(((9*4)+(x+8))*(6-5))"));
assertTrue(isFormula("6"));
assertTrue(isFormula("(3+1)"));
assertFalse(isFormula("-6"));
assertFalse(isFormula("(1+*(x+2)*(1-6))"));
assertFalse(isFormula("( (6+x))"));
assertFalse(isFormula("10"));
assertFalse(isFormula("2+x"));
assertFalse(isFormula("(33+3)"));
assertFalse(isFormula("((1+2))"));
```

Or you can also do it without regular expression.

```
static boolean isFormula(String s) {
    return new Object() {
        int index = 0;

        boolean match(String expects) {
            if (index >= s.length() || expects.indexOf(s.charAt(index)) < 0)
                return false;
            ++index;
            return true;
        }

        boolean formula() {
            if (match("0123456789x"))
                return true;
            return match("(")
                && formula() && match("+-*/%") && formula()
                && match(")");
        }

        boolean parse() {
            return formula() && index >= s.length();
        }
    }.parse();
}
```

Comment: First of all, thank you so much! However, I can't see where is the recursion, when the requirement is that "isFormula" has to be recursive. Now I see that formula() using recursion isn't it? this comment belongs to the second method...